# Floating menu on transition menu fades from right

Tags: jquery, css

I've been trying to create a floating menu for couple weeks and over and over I fail.
The problem now is, when I'm scrolling down the page the menu floats also, I've added some style when he floats like `transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out` and changed the `height` and `backgroundgcolor` and stuff on **jQuery code**, not in the **CSS**.
So, when I scroll down there's supposed to be a transition, but instead it fades from the right. Meaning it comes from the right and then it scrolls and changes the height.
[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yugeteze/6)
But something weird, if I do it once it does come from the right but if I do it more 1,000 times, it will be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more clear about your EXPECTED result VS what's actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bar in "fixed" mode attached to right side before you set css-setting in jquery. You can check this, if add style to element

```
<div class="navgroups" style="
    position: fixed;
">
```

Fix them, and animation will be fun.

Set width as your BODY block(parent block) also:

```
<div class="navgroups" style="
        position: fixed;
        width: 76%;
    ">
```

Comment: But then, my menu floats to right instead of being center

Comment: still need for help... my menu is on the right side instead of center, though I've `margin: 0 auto` it.

Comment: Your body has width 76%. navgroups: width: 100% (relatively BODY). If you set navgroups.position: fixed, he set relatively ALL WINDOW. Also set width: 76% and jumps will not.

Answer (score 0):

You're transitioning from *width:100%;* to width: *974px;* Set the width on your class from the beginning.